# How to set title in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

View application.html.erb contains following content

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : t(:stocktaking_title) %></title>
```

How can I pass data to this view from the controller's method?
I mean use symbol `:title`. I'm don't know Ruby well.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def download
    view_context.content_for(:title, "My Awesome Title") # doesn't work :( 
  end
end
```

Rails 4.1.9, ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

Answer (score 2):

The prependeded `@` character to a variable is what exposes the variable to the view scope. In your controller:

```
def show
  @title = "My Title"
end
```

Will let any rendered template file access it using:

```
<%= @title %>
```

Clearly, you're looking for some sort of title processing logic. Perhaps you could try replacing the code in your `application.html.erb` file with something like:

```
<% if @title %>
    <title><%= @title %></title>
<% elsif content_for?(:title) %>
   <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
<% else %>
   <title><%= t(:stocktaking_title) %></title>
<% end %>
```

You could condense this into a ternary but the view wouldn't be very readable.

If you insist on using `content_for` inside of the controller, you can use the [`view_context`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context) method, but you can't seem to work with `content_for` directly like so:

```
view_context.content_for(:title, "My Awesome Title")
```

Instead, you'll need to implement your own `content_for` method to extend off of the `view_context`. I [pulled it from this Gist](https://gist.github.com/hiroshi/985457), but here's the code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  # FORCE to implement content_for in controller
  def view_context
    super.tap do |view|
      (@_content_for || {}).each do |name,content|
        view.content_for name, content
      end
    end
  end
  def content_for(name, content) # no blocks allowed yet
    @_content_for ||= {}
    if @_content_for[name].respond_to?(:<<)
      @_content_for[name] << content
    else
      @_content_for[name] = content
    end
  end
  def content_for?(name)
    @_content_for[name].present?
  end
end
```

This has been tested and works.

Then just do `content_for :title, "My Awesome Title"` in your controller.

Seriously though, using `@title` will be way way easier and less "hacky." You could even do something cool like this:

```
<title><%= @title || content_for(:title) || t(:stocktaking_title) %></title>
```

Comment: I just want to use symbol `:title`, I don't want to change everything.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. I updated question, it has proper formatting.

Comment: @zoonman I made an update that works. I really don't like it versus the alternative, though.

Comment: Yes, it looks like one guy already put this patch into gem https://github.com/clm-a/content_for_in_controllers

Comment: It is a little bit ridiculous do not have such simple and often used thing in controller.